# Debug Javascript in Komodo Extension

Tags: javascript, debugging, komodo

You can put `alert(SOMETHING)` into Javascript code to catch errors or see what is happening.

Most of the time this is fine. But if you want to show a lot of information (like the properties on an object) the alert box is no good. Is it possible in Komodo IDE to log to a Komodo window or a file?

To make it a bit harder this is for Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding this call:

```
window.openDialog('chrome://global/content/console.xul', '_blank');
```

to where you initialize your extension. This will show you the error messages you get. Just remember to remove it before publishing. :)

Also, you can log stuff to pystderr.log via:

```
ko.logging.getLogger("extensions.myextension").warn("foo");
```

Use eg. JSON.stringify to dump objects.

Third, install [Komodo developer extension](http://community.activestate.com/node/1824) to try things out in a Javascript console.

Comment: Oh, forgot to mention that you can view `pystderr.log` from Help -> Troubleshooting -> View Log File.

Comment: Good. But how do you write an informational message into this dialog?